# pcolormesh not plotting bins as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I'm trying to plot irregularly spaced data using pcolormesh. The x data indicate labels, while the y array identifies the start TIME (lets say sec) of a measurement. Hence, I expect the vertical bins to map to starting times [1,2,5,6,12,13] with the bins colored appropriately. But I get something completely different (which I can't understand):

```
cmap = plt.cm.jet
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

cax = ax.pcolormesh([20,30,40], [1,2,5,6,12,13], 
                                     np.array([[1,2,5], #1
                                               [0,2,0], #2
                                               [1,2,3], #5
                                               [2,2,0], #6
                                               [3,2,3], #12
                                               [4,2,0]]), #13
                    cmap=cmap, alpha=1)
ax.set_xticks(range(20,41,10))
ax.set_yticks(range(1,15))
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
```

Results in this plot:

[image]

What is going on? I expect the lower left, first entry, to go from (20,1) to (30,2) -- which it does if you center the labels... But going up the y axis (according to the documentation) should go from (20,2) to (30, 5) which it does not. The next up should start at (5,20) and go to (6,30) but again no!?!? How do I get the data (colors) to match the bounds of my x-y array???

The real data also exhibits this issue in x... so I must not be using it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you supply for X and Y are not just the "upper edge" of the rectangles.  The numbers are taken in pairs.  So, your first bracket spans 1 to 2, not 0 to 1.  You don't have anything covering the Y from 0 to 1.

If you change it to this, the display becomes what you expect:

```
cax = ax.pcolormesh([10,20,30,40], [0,1,2,5,6,12,13],
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks... Yep, I actually figured it out a few min after entering the question. However, thanks again: this may help someone else!